# Illustrator - Counters. Need to separate from letter - HOW?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am working on a project and I need to separate the counters from the actual letter. I don't want to delete the counters - I just need to separate them. Please help me!!!  MANY MANY thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.. assuming type has been converted to outlines.... (if not `Type > Create Outlines`.) 
It is not possible to alter counters on *live* type.

---

In some instance all one need do is...

Select the glyph, then choose `Object > Compound Path > Release`.

---

If the above doesn't work....

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow).

Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key.

Click *just the path* for the counter. It's important that you *only* click the path. You should see the entire path for the *counter* highlight and *not* the entire character.

Once the counter is highlighted.... `Object > Cut` and then `Object > Paste in Front`. 
<sub>(<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)</sub>

This will copy the path for the counter, remove the counter, then paste an identical path on top that does *not* act as a counter.

Comment: THANK YOU!  The second method worked.